# nullpointer exception on connectivitymanager

Tags: android

```
public boolean isOnline() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnectedOrConnecting();}
```

I'm getting a nullpointer on `return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo`.

I tried `this.getSystemService` but also didn't work. Maybe its because my activity extends a super activity i've created and I'm grabbing the context incorrectly...? tried `getBaseContext()` too

Answer (score 1):

With two methods chained together on the return line, are you sure it's the `ConnectivityManager` coming back null?  It's perfectly valid for `ConnectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo()` to return `null` instead of a valid `NetworkInfo` object when there is no active network.  If this comes back `null`, then it is the call to `NetworkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()` that is throwing the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Guess #1:

Do you have these in your manifest?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE">
```